# Modal displaying differently on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile, modal-dialog

I have a modal triggered by an image that I have set to display at the bottom of the page as below:

```
.modal-dialog {
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

This works fine on desktop browsers and on safari, but it's displaying at the top on chrome and firefox mobile.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your head tag on the html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Still the same issue I'm afraid!

Comment: im not sure I can see enough code from you. But try putting left:0 or make sure that the div's parent container is position: relative

Comment: Is the div with id: shareModal position:relative?

Comment: Yes it is. Modal-dialog is fixed, modal-content is relative

Comment: I loaded it into my html template here, and viewed in chrome mobile, they are at the bottom, not sure what to tell you.  I can't help you because it's working for me. There must be a problem with something other then the code you provided.